# Can't get a script to run on starting an ec2 ubuntu server

Tags: server, scripts, cron, amazon-ec2, init

So I have an EC2 instance setup, but in order for it to work the way I'd like to, I need to execute a script every time the EC2 instance is started, but for the life of me I cannot get the script to start when I start the instance. My EC2 instance is **Ubuntu server 16**, here's what I've tried so far

- adding `@reboot /path/to/myScript.sh` to `crontab` for `root` user
- adding `myScript.sh` to the `/etc/init.d` folder as well as the `/etc/init` folder
- adding `/path/to/myScript.sh` to my `rc.local`
- copying the script to `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot`

Manually executing the script as root will work perfectly, but none of the above methods has worked for me, I'm not sure what I could possibly be missing here.

If it matters, what I'm trying to accomplish is to use `yas3fs` to mount an `s3` bucket as a fs to `/mnt` which will contain media. Unfortunately `yas3fs` doesn't work in the `fstab`, so I need to execute the mounting command as a script.

Comment: All of the commands in your script may need fully qualified paths... e.g., not `yas3fs` but `/usr/local/bin/yas3fs` (or whatever the path to the executable may be).  The search path available to cronjobs or `/etc/rc.local`, etc., contains fewer and/or different directories than you'll have with an interactive shell.  Try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Make sure the file is executable.
Set execute permission on your script:

```
chmod +x /path/myScript.sh
```

Enable logs : it will help you out with exact problem.

```
@reboot /path/to/myScript.sh > /path/cronlog.log 2>&1
```